# Find/Inspect Dom Elements of HTTP Authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, authentication

I have used the search engine on both Stack & Google, but can not find an answer to my question.

When a site is using http auth to get username/password, can the "form" elements of the pop-up that is displayed be inspected?

Example: https://www.brisnet.com/secure-bin/brisclub/login_redirect.cgi

When you load that page, you are presented with a pop-up, but I believe this popup is http authentication.. I have tried every way I know to find the name of these two fields, but have failed..

Is it even possible to accomplish this?

I am trying to find what name is used for posting these two fields when you click "Log In".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Interesting. Looking at this now.. Still not sure if what I am trying to do is possible tho.